# How do I make sure that when a .h file is modified, the .cc files including it are compiled automatically in a Release build using Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

Say I have a.h, a.cc, and b.cc in my Visual Studio 2008 project. Both a.cc and b.cc include a.h. When I modify a.h, and build the Project, a.cc and b.cc are compiled in the Debug builds. However, that is not the case in Release builds. In the Release builds, a.cc and b.cc are compiled only if they have been modified. It seems that the compiler does not keep track of the dependencies of .cc files in the Release builds.

Is there some compiler flag that will fix this problem? If not, are there other methods to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 4):

The compiler should be doing that automatically, though the problem does arise occasionally, by touching the files, interacting with source control, or even daylight savings.  In the "Build" menu, select "Clean" and that should reset all the temporary files, which should make everything re-synchronize.

> Also if you change your system clock between compiles. I have to do
>   this sometimes when testing things. – John Dibling

Comment: Visual Studio get itself in a tis about these things every now and again. Possibly the best way to solve the problem is to use a more up to date version of Visual Studio.

Comment: @Will: I know the newest versions of Visual Studio have much improved intellisense and databases, but neither of those should be related to this issue.  I know of no updates to Visual Studio WRT building out of date files.

Comment: I wasn't being too serious about it. I have no empirical evidence, only anecdotal, but I have found that 2010 seems to be far better at deciding what to recompile.