# Inconsistent build when a function template is modified in the header file underVS2012

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012, compilation, linker

I have a visual studio solution that uses multiple projects. I find a strange behavior with compiling/linking using VS2012 under  debug mode. I have a project 'X', and it has a header file "A.h" contains

```
template <class T>
double Test( const T & in) //first function
{
std::cout<<"1\n";
return 0.0;
}

template <class T>
T Test( const T & in, const bool in) //second function
{
std::cout<<"2\n";
return T(0.0);
}

 void dTest(dataType in)
{
Test(in)
}

void TTest(dataType in);
```

and "A.cpp"

```
#include "A.h"
void TTest(dataType in)
{
Test (in, true);
}
```

Then some where in the solution I call TTest and dTest.

It prints  1 and 2 as expected.

Then I change code to print 3 and 4 respectively;

and build, which leads to compilation of A.cpp. 
However when I run it prints 3 and 2.

It I try to place a break point in the first function it reaches there.
However if I set break point in the second function, the debugger complains "break point will not be hit. Source code version is different".

I could not reproduce this behavior in "release" mode, yet. Doing a rebuild brings correct behavior. Why do I see this behavior? There is a single dll file created for each project. How can it have part from current code and part from previous code?. I am working with TFS systetm. Does this mean, VS keeps an intermediate file that is different from my current file?

Any insights/solution to the problem (apart from rebuild/clean) appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio doesn't do a good job of tracking dependencies. See [How do I make sure that when a .h file is modified, the .cc files including it are compiled automatically in a Release build using Visual Studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982025/how-do-i-make-sure-that-when-a-h-file-is-modified-the-cc-files-including-it-a).

If you modify a .h file, the only safe method to make sure that the change takes effect is to rebuild all the projects in the solution.

**PS**

In my experience, the dependencies get picked up correctly in debug builds. The problem is only in release builds.

Comment: well.. as mentioned in the question I am aware about rebuild working properly( In fact I did not have to rebuild entirely..only the project that was modified)

Comment: @user6386155, if you are using a release build, the safest method is to rebuild all the Projects in a solution since dependencies are not tracked accurately in release builds.