# Visual Studio 2019 not building all cpp files when a header file changes

Tags: c++, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I have been trying to figure out why visual studio has not been recompiling all the compilation units affected by a header file change in my Library project.

Lets say I have the following header file `TestA.h`:

```
class TestA
{
    public:
    int GetNumber() { return 0 };

    std::string GetString(); // implemented in TestA.cpp

}
```

Lets say I then have 3 .cpp files `TestA.cpp` `TestB.cpp` `TestC.cpp`

`TestA.cpp` Only contains the function implementations for `TestA`

However both `TestB.cpp` and `TestC.cpp` follow something of the sort:

```
#include "TestA.h"

....

TestA* aObject = new TestA();

int aNumber = aObject->GetNumber();

...
```

This is where the problem now lays, if I change the function `GetNumber` in TestA.h to `GetNumber1` Visual studio and msbuild command line will only build TestA.cpp and it will succeed in compiling. It will then generate the .lib using the now stale .obj files. If I however rebuild then I get the errors that I do expect. I have tried enabling/disabling Incremental linking, minimal rebuilding, Managed Incremental Build.

I can achieve the desired behavior by deleting the .obj and the .tlog files from my intermediate directory.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks
Sumeth

Comment: I asked the question a few years ago and I haven't gotten a satisfactory answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982025/how-do-i-make-sure-that-when-a-h-file-is-modified-the-cc-files-including-it-a.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after exhausting all my ideas I decided to try and just recreate the project. And that fixed it! Not sure what exactly happened but deleting all the vcxproj files and recreating the vcxproj from scratch fixed my issue. Not sure what exactly changed but that seemed to solve it

Comment: You could click `√` under your answer. [Click the button like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png).

Comment: I ran into the exact same issue. Based on your answer, I looked at the .vcxproj file and found the issue. The .cpp file was not included for compilation (using `<ClInclude Include="MyFile.cpp" />`). It was included as a non-code file (using `<None Include="IFilter.h" />`) for some odd reason. I replaced `None` with `ClInclude` and then it worked. Your recreating the .vcxproj file did essentially the same thing.